# SQL- Запрос с параметром

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день.

Как делать запросы с параметром как в MS Aсcess? Допустим показать имена учащихся код которых будет вводится с клавиатуры? Возможно ли это сделать без функций и процедур?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: *как в MS Aсcess* Нет. MS Access - это клиент и сервер в одном флаконе. А MS SQL - только сервер. Ввод значения параметра реализуется на клиенте.

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь понятно.